# Apt-get installers: how does it works

Tags: ubuntu, installation, apt-get

I need to learn new aspect of development: making apt-get installers. Because of it, I need to find out, how it works. I tried to search information about it, but 90% of it is apt-get man's.

For example: user prints `sudo apt-get install package_name`, and what? Is there installation script on server from `sources.list` file? If yes, how does it execute on client's computer?

I'll be glad to learn it with your help. May be it's stupid question, but I really can't find necessary information about this topic. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is apt-get download package from server which sources.list includes and execute install script. Long answer is you can study the debian developer document from http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/best-pkging-practices.html.